# Squeak smalltalk: why can't I activate the do it menu

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I downloaded squeak 4.2 http://squeak.org/ and watch this very basic tutorial
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0w1Yub4eUAU

When I type 2 + 2 in workspace window and select right-click the line I can't get any popup menu with "do it" option.

Did I miss something ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your platform and configuration that menu may be activated either by a right-click or a middle-click. For Squeak on Windows I believe the default is to middle-click.

If the default feels unintuitive you can invert the right and middle mouse buttons.

To invert the mouse buttons for the current image:

- Click on the world background
- Select *open...* from the World menu
- Select *Preference Browser*
- Search for *mouse* in the preferences
- Toggle *swapMouseButtons*

To invert the mouse buttons on the Windows VM:

- Open the system menu (small Squeak icon in the top-left window corner)
- Under *VM Preferrences > Mouse mapping* toggle *3 button mouse*

You can also activate that menu by ALT-clicking or use the quicker ALT-d shortcut for "do it".